# Postgresql jsonb default insert value with dynamic timestamp

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a `status` column in my postgres database with the type `jsonb`

I can prepopulate the json with something like this.

`CREATE TABLE ...
  status jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '{"hello": "world"}'
 ...`

But what I am asking and what I would like to have is a JSON property with a timestamp prepolulated using the function `now()`

`CREATE TABLE ...
  status jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '{"created_at": "'now()'"}'
 ...`

`CREATE TABLE ...
  status jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '{"created_at": "'+now()'+"}'
 ...`

Unfortunately these approaches above do not work. What would be the way to do it?

Comment: That's like buying a small piece chocolate wrapped in a ton of plastic. A big waste. Just store the timestamp as `timestamptz` (8 bytes) instead of your `jsonb` occupying 58 bytes.

Comment: In general I totally agree with you. To be fair this represents only a small abstraction and not the complete use case and the json is going to be enriched over time with not know properties yet. So for today I feel good with it and in future I might change it =) And it is also good to know how things like this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create the JSONB at runtime using [jsonb_build_object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
CREATE TABLE foobar 
    (status jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT jsonb_build_object('created_at', now()));
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ba13df/1).

Comment: Glad to help you @silverfighter